# How To Use Uniswap's Flash Swap / Debug "Fail" Reversion?

Tags: solidity, etherscan, uniswap, swaps

I'm on Goerli and attempting to use Uniswap's .swap() transaction described [here](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/V2/guides/smart-contract-integration/using-flash-swaps).

If my understanding is correct, if I set one of the amounts to 0 and another amount to nonzero, and bytes as non-zero length, it'll trigger a loan to call uniswapV2Call. So as a simple contract, I just did something like this:

```
    function borrow(
        address token0, address token1, uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1,
        address _factory
    ) external {
        address pairAddress = IUniswapV2Factory(_factory).getPair(
            token0,
            token1
        );
        require(pairAddress != address(0), "This pool does not exist");
        IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress).swap(
            amount0,
            amount1,
            address(this),
            bytes("asdf")
        );
        require(1 == 0, "asdf");
    }
    function uniswapV2Call(
        address _sender, uint256 _amount0, uint256 _amount1, address _factory,
        bytes calldata _data
    ) external {
         // code is never reached.
        require(1==0,"This is called!");
       
    }
}
```

The problem is that the callback uniswapV2Call is never reached. I just get 'FAIL' like [this](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xf20942b083e05f1c5efe1bc07479e54c4ec8d8109891fd300caf95a575c9d945). I've determined the code stops execution at the line `IUniswapV2Pair(pairAddress).swap()` where I've determined the amount0, amount1, and pairAddress seen by that line of code are: `0`, `23771311032997121`, `0x28CEE28A7C4B4022AC92685C07D2F33AB1A0E122` respectively by a require that was slipped right before the `.swap()` call:

```
        string memory errMsg = string(
            abi.encodePacked(
                Strings.toString(amount0),
                ",",
                Strings.toString(amount1),
                ",",
                Strings.toString(uint256(uint160(pairAddress)))
            )
        );
        require(1 == 0, errMsg);
```

This pool pair is just WETH-UNI on Goerli, so I'd imagine I'd be able to loan .1 ETH's worth against it and at least trigger a callback? I'm pretty stuck on this because tracing the Pair's contract's `swap()` function, all their `require` has some sort of `UniswapV2` tag to clue in where the failure's happened. But it just says `Fail` which could mean anything so I'm pretty stuck as to:

1. How do I debug 'fail' errors that are just generic?
2. Why does this call to `swap` fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ended up being a typo in my contract. The callback in question takes 4 args, as was said, but the implementation above is taking 5 args, which kills the function. So while the reason for failure is obfuscated on-chain, the callback is basically an error of "uniswapV2Call has 4 arguments, expected 5."

Answer (score 0):

From the [transaction trace](https://goerli.etherscan.io/vmtrace?txhash=0xf20942b083e05f1c5efe1bc07479e54c4ec8d8109891fd300caf95a575c9d945&type=parity), the Uniswap2Pair (`0x28cee28a7c4b4022ac92685c07d2f33ab1a0e122`) calls the contract (`0x5893ec43bbc0bb2e08806e17b181f9191d19e591`).

The function called has selector `0x10d1e85c`, from the [Ethereum Signature Database](https://www.4byte.directory/signatures/?bytes4_signature=0x10d1e85c) it correspond to `uniswapV2Call(address,uint256,uint256,bytes)`.

It is something in your function implementation that causes the revertion.

[image]